# How long should I cook herbal ghee?

Tags: butter, herbs, ghee

How long do you simmer the ghee with the herbs?  Does it depend on what herbs I'm using?

Comment: Welcome! I've edited out the bit of the question about favorites, because we don't do questions about "what goes with X?" or "what do you like best?" here -they're subjective and have a lot of possible answers. The rest of the question is great, though!

Answer (score 1):

Dried herbs take less time than fresh (dried herbs are usually more concentrated than the fresh).  That said, I can't say that I stick to any certain time, just simmer until the ghee begins to smell aromatic.